# Jest spy on super class method 'No overload matches this call'

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, inheritance, jestjs, nestjs

I have the unit testing of a code in nestjs, where basicly i have a services that extends from a another class, in that class i update the record that has been passed by the function and set the status as inactive. When i'm trying to mock the function inactivate of the UsersService, it works one time, if a do some changes to the test it fails (for example add some white spaces), if i changes again (it success again). Every time that i change the test file, it fails or success, but never twice in a row.

```
@Injectable({ scope: Scope.REQUEST })
export class UsersService extends DataProvider<User> {

  constructor(
    @Inject(REQUEST)
    private readonly _userRequest: Request,
    @InjectRepository(User)
    private readonly _userRepository: Repository<User>,
    private readonly _configService: ConfigService,
    @Inject(forwardRef(() => TokensService))
    private readonly _tokenService: TokensService,
    private readonly _rolesService: RolesService,
  ) {
    super(_userRequest, _userRepository);
  }


  /**
   * Get user by id
   * @param {number} id - id of the user to be found
   * @returns {Promise<User>} - User in system
   */
  async getById(id: number): Promise<User> {
    const user = await this._userRepository
      .findOneOrFail({
        where: { id, status: Not(StatusEnum.deleted) },
      })
      .catch(() => {
        throw new ForbiddenException({
          success: false,
          message: 'You do not have permission on user.',
        });
      });

    return this.format(user);
  }


  /**
   * Inactivate user
   * @param {number} id - id of the user to be activated
   * @returns {Promise<User>} - Inactivate User
   */
  async inactivate(id: number): Promise<User> {
    return await this.inactivateByStatus(await this.getById(id));
  }
}
```

Data Provider

```
export class DataProvider<Entity extends ObjectLiteral> {
  constructor(
    private readonly _request: Request,
    private readonly _repository: Repository<Entity>,
  ) {}

  /**
   * Set the status of the entity as Inactive
   * @param {Entity} entity - entity to inactivate
   * @param {number} [user] - User performing the request
   * @returns {Promise<Entity>} - Inactivated Entity
   */
  protected async inactivateByStatus(
    entity: Entity,
    user?: number,
  ): Promise<Entity> {
    return this.updateEntity(entity, { status: StatusEnum.inactive }, user);
  }

}
```

When i perform testing on inactivate function, sometimes works and sometimes dont (without making any change to the code)

Error:

```
    src/modules/users/test/users.service.spec.ts:55:25 - error TS2769: No overload matches this call.
      Overload 1 of 4, '(object: UsersService, method: FunctionPropertyNames<Required<UsersService>>): SpyInstance<Promise<void> | Promise<...> | Promise<...> | Promise<...>, [id: ...] | ... 7 more ... | [id: ...]>', gave the following error.
        Argument of type '"inactivateByStatus"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'FunctionPropertyNames<Required<UsersService>>'.
      Overload 2 of 4, '(object: UsersService, method: never): SpyInstance<never, never>', gave the following error.
        Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.

    55     jest.spyOn(service, 'inactivateByStatus').mockImplementation(() => {
```

Test Working:

[image: Test working]